# issue with nav and float right

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am tring to display two div inside a nav on the rigth, the problem is that if I set this div `<div _ngcontent-c9="" class=" ng-clock docs-homepage-row menuSup">` as float: right in the css, it will not goes on the right part of the screen.

```
   <nav _ngcontent-c1="" class=" ng-clock docs-navbar-header menuDate">
     <div _ngcontent-c9="" class=" ng-clock docs-homepage-row menuSup">


       <div _ngcontent-c9="" class=" ng-clock docs-homepage-promo-img">
         ...
      </div>

      <div _ngcontent-c9="" class=" ng-clock docs-homepage-promo-img" >
         ...
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>
```

CSS

```
.docs-navbar-header[_ngcontent-c1] {
display : flex;
flex-wrap : wrap;
align-items : center;
padding : 12px 16px;
}

.menuDate{
  width: 100%;
  background: var(--defaultColorDark);
}

.docs-homepage-row[_ngcontent-c9] {
display : flex;
max-width : 920px;
margin : 60px 0;
float: right;
}

.menuSup[_ngcontent-c9] {
display : flex;
width: 100%;
margin : 10px 10px;
float: right;
}

.docs-homepage-row[_ngcontent-c9] .docs-svg-image[_ngcontent-c9] {
max-width : 90%;
}

.docs-homepage-promo-desc[_ngcontent-c9], .docs-homepage-promo-img[_ngcontent-c9] {
width : 50%;
}
.docs-homepage-promo-img[_ngcontent-c9] {
text-align : center;
margin-top: 20px;

}
```

Comment: what exactly you want its not clear. You have applied `width:100%` and `float: right`. So how do you know it is right or left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many options to achieve what you need, but using `float` property is not the best one. Each following options will be interesting depending of the context.

**[OPTION #1]** (recommended)

If `.docs-homepage-row.menuSup` is the only one child of `.docs-navbar-header.menuDate`, you can simply apply `justify-content: flex-end;` to `.docs-navbar-header.menuDate`.

Learn more about Flexbox there : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

**[OPTION #2]** (usefull)

Apply `margin-left: auto;` to `.docs-homepage-row.menuSup` will push the flex-item to the right.

**[OPTION #3]** (not recommended)

If, for some reason, you really need to use `float`, be aware that you need to "clear" the next element. The best way to achieve it, it's to use the clearfix hack on the parent.

You can learn more about the clearfix hack on the following link : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/